# Why is this xmlreader code not working?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have a file that looks like this:

```
    <ExternalPage about="http://animation.about.com/">
       <d:Title>About.com: Animation Guide</d:Title>
       <d:Description>Keep up with developments in online animation for all skill levels.     Download tools, and seek inspiration from online work.</d:Description>
       <topic>Top/Arts/Animation</topic>
    </ExternalPage>
    <ExternalPage about="http://www.toonhound.com/">
       <d:Title>Toonhound</d:Title>
       <d:Description>British cartoon, animation and comic strip creations - links, reviews  and news from the UK.</d:Description>
       <topic>Top/Arts/Animation</topic>
    </ExternalPage>
```

etc.

I'm trying to get the "about" url, as well as the nested title and description. I've tried the following code, but all I get is a bunch of dashes...

```
$reader = new XMLReader();

if (!$reader->open("dbpedia/links/xml.xml")) {
die("Failed to open 'xml.xml'");
}
$num=0;
while($reader->read() && $num<200) {
if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'ExternalPage') {
$url = $reader->getAttribute('about');

while ($xml->nodeType !== XMLReader::END_ELEMENT ){
$reader->read();

 if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'd:Title') {
 $title=$xmlReader->value;
 }
elseif ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'd:Description') {
$desc=$xmlReader->value;
}
}

}
$num++;echo $url."-".$title."-".$desc."<br />";
}
$reader->close();
```

I'm new at xmlreader, so I'd appreciate it if someone can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Note: I'm using xmlreader because the file is a huge one (millions of lines).

EDIT: The beginning of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns:r="http://www.w3.org/TR/RDF/" xmlns:d="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.0/"       xmlns="http://dmoz.org/rdf/">
  <!-- Generated at 2013-02-10 00:03:45 EST from DMOZ 2.0 -->
  <Topic r:id="">
<catid>1</catid>
  </Topic>
<Topic r:id="Top/Arts">
    <catid>381773</catid>
  </Topic>
  <Topic r:id="Top/Arts/Animation">
  <catid>423945</catid>
<link1 r:resource="http://www.awn.com/"></link1>
<link r:resource="http://animation.about.com/"></link>
<link r:resource="http://www.toonhound.com/"></link>
<link r:resource="http://enculturation.gmu.edu/2_1/pisters.html"></link>
<link r:resource="http://www.digitalmediafx.com/Features/animationhistory.html"></link>
<link r:resource="http://www.spark-online.com/august00/media/romano.html"></link>
<link r:resource="http://www.animated-divots.net/"></link>
</Topic>
<ExternalPage about="http://www.awn.com/">
<d:Title>Animation World Network</d:Title>
<d:Description>Provides information resources to the international animation community. Features include searchable database archives, monthly magazine, web animation guide, the Animation Village, discussion forums and other useful resources.</d:Description>
<priority>1</priority>
<topic>Top/Arts/Animation</topic>
</ExternalPage>
```

etc

Comment: can you namespace declaration of `d:` and root tag to the sample XML?

Comment: @DoSparKot I added the entire first part of the file to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll take time and proper debugging to come up with working pure XMLReader code. Meanwhile try this hybrid method:

```
$xmlR = new XMLReader;
$xmlR->open('dbpedia/links/xml.xml');

//Skip until <ExternalPage> node
while ($xmlR->read() && $xmlR->name !== 'ExternalPage');

$loadedNS_f = false;
while ($xmlR->name === 'ExternalPage')
{
    //Read the entire parent tag with children
    $sxmlNode = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlR->readOuterXML());

    //collect all namespaces in node recursively once; assuming all nodes are similar
    if (!$loadedNS_f) {
        $tagNS = $sxmlNode->getNamespaces(true);
        $loadedNS_f = true; 
    }
    $URL = (string) $sxmlNode['about'];
    $dNS = $sxmlNode->children($tagNS['d']);
    $Title = (string) $dNS->Title;
    $Desc = (string) $dNS->Description;
    $Topic = (string)$sxmlNode->topic;

    var_dump($URL, $Title, $Desc, $Topic);

    // Jump to next <ExternalPage> tag
    $xmlR->next('ExternalPage');
}

$xmlR->close();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I was worried it may be slow because it isn't pure xmlreader, but it processed over 120k records in about 20 seconds, so that's pretty good!

Comment: There is no real need to go into SimpleXML via XML string buffers. For the elements node values, you can use the `DOMNode->nodeValue` available via `XMLReader::expand()->nodeValue`, and children are easy to parse, too, when you encapsulate that yourself a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14904227/367456 - would be interesting to see if that makes some difference after all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is not working for you is because you only read to the start-tag of the `d:Title` element and that one got no value:

```
if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'd:Title') {
    $title=$xmlReader->value;
}
```

You probably wanted to get the nodeValue of that DOM element, but that is not what `$xmlReader->value` will return. Knowing this there are multiple ways to deal with that:

1. Expand the node ([`XMLReader::expand()`](http://php.net/XMLReader.expand)) and get the `nodeValue` (quick example):

   ```
   $title = $reader->expand()->nodeValue;
   ```
2. Process all `XMLReader::TEXT (3)`  and/or `XMLReader::CDATA (4)` child-nodes your own (decide if a node is a child-node by looking into [`XMLReader::$depth`](http://php.net/class.xmlreader.php#xmlreader.props.depth)).

In any case to streamline your code you can consider to provide what you need directly, for example by creating yourself a set of functions your own or extend the XMLReader class:

```
class MyXMLReader extends XMLReader
{
    public function readToNextElement()
    {
        while (
            $result = $this->read()
            and $this->nodeType !== self::ELEMENT
        ) ;
        return $result;
    }

    public function readToNext($localname)
    {
        while (
            $result = $this->readToNextElement()
            and $this->localName !== $localname
        ) ;
        return $result;
    }

    public function readToNextChildElement($depth)
    {
        // if the current element is the parent and
        // empty there are no children to go into
        if ($this->depth == $depth && $this->isEmptyElement) {
            return false;
        }

        while ($result = $this->read()) {
            if ($this->depth <= $depth) return false;
            if ($this->nodeType === self::ELEMENT) break;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getNodeValue($default = NULL)
    {
        $node = $this->expand();
        return $node ? $node->nodeValue : $default;
    }
}
```

You can then just use this extended class to do your processing:

```
$reader = new MyXMLReader();
$reader->open($uri);

$num = 0;
while ($reader->readToNext('ExternalPage') and $num < 200) {
    $url = $reader->getAttribute('about');

    $depth = $reader->depth;
    $title = $desc = '';

    while ($reader->readToNextChildElement($depth)) {
        switch ($reader->localName) {
            case 'Title':
                $title = $reader->getNodeValue();
                break;
            case 'Description':
                $desc = trim($reader->getNodeValue());
                break;
        }
    }

    $num++;
    echo "#", $num, ": ", $url, " - ", $title, " - ", $desc, "<br />\n";
}
```

As you can see, this has dramatically made your code much more readable. Also you do not need to care each time if you read this all right.

Comment: Pure XMLReader, I still don't understand why it's nearly five time slower? I expected at least 20% faster performance. Can we optimise further?

Comment: You can try to only do the `expand` operation in *your* code-example. It might be that the looping is not optimized (especially here with children). Also you might consider that `XMLReader` is much faster but your documents aren't really big so it maybe does not make any use. You might want to look into XML parser: http://php.net/book.xml.php - it can process XML chunks.

Comment: I had X-Debug features enabled earlier; I disabled them. I tested with 6500 <ExternalPage> xml tags file. Anywaysz... Now it's nearly twice slower.

Comment: I do not see your code so it's hard to give you any concrete feedback. Which two codes are you comparing with each other? And 6500 tags does not sound large to me at all for an XML document. You really might have over-optimized yourself by choosing `XML_Reader`. A simple SimpleXML in the first place might even be much faster, especially running some xpath queries.

Comment: OPs XML has millions of records. Code compared: Mine [XMLReader + SimpleXML combo](http://pastebin.com/YT6r54dt) and yours [eXtended XMLReader](http://pastebin.com/t5TTtPP3).

Comment: You got some sample XML to feed in? Just pick an DMOZ dump of some category?

Comment: It has to be local file, don't you think? Repeat OPs XML tags if you can. It doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: I was asking where to fetch the XML file so that I can compare the scripts ;) - sure stored to disk for tests - will try getting some natural data.

Comment: Can you explain how can i use it i this case:
`while ($xml->readToNextChildElement($depth)) {
                        switch ($xml->localName) {
                            case 'Images':
echo 'the Image Attribute 'url' for each image.';
break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate way to get to that attribute:

```
$string = file_get_contents($filename);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('/RDF/ExternalPage[*]/@about');
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: my understanding is that simplexml doesnt work well at all with large files, which is why I'm working with xmlreader.

Comment: Try it and see. I think you'll be surprised. @DoSparKot has a good hybrid solution.