# LOAD XML INFILE from inconsistant XML file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

How can I use  LOAD XML INFILE on an xml like this one. I tried to loop through it with simplexml_load_file in php, but this file is so huge that the script stopped running after a few hours. I have no clue how to use LOAD XML INFILE. I did try to read the documentation but couldn't figure out how it works in my case where there are multiple category fields in each item and they're all named the same.

```
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <category>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Accessories</name>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>15</id>
        <name>Home Accessories</name>
    </category>
</item>
<item>
    <id>2</id>
    <category>
        <id>13</id>
        <name>Tools</name>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>39</id>
        <name>Power Tools</name>
    </category>
    <bullet>
        <point>Will cut plywood, OSB, paneling and finish cut pine</point>
        <seqNbr>10</seqNbr>
    </bullet>
    <bullet>
        <point>Smooth celcon slider locks blade in position</point>
        <seqNbr>40</seqNbr>
    </bullet>
</item>
```

Also some items have additional fields like attributes and bullet points, and they're not consistent, meaning one can have 2 attributes and another will have 10.

Comment: I tried to loop through it with simplexml_load_file in php, but this file is so huge that the script stopped running after a few hours. I have no clue how to use LOAD XML INFILE

Comment: I tried to read the documentation but couldn't figure out how it works in my case where there are multiple category fields in each item and they're all named the same.

Comment: [process LargeXML using XMLReader & SimpleXML combo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884440/why-is-this-xmlreader-code-not-working/14885108#14885108) see if you can adopt it.

Comment: Include some different types of `<item>` tags in the question for clarity.

Comment: you should first use some XSL to streamline the XML and the pipe it into mysql. your linux OS should ship with all the tools for that, using PHP is still possible but seems a bit akward.